# A new Azure network security group not working

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-nsg

I've got an Azure service fabric setup and I'd like the back end services to be able to make calls to an external API.

To this end I have created a Network Security Group instance and set the subnet to be that of the backend subnet of the service fabric setup. I have then added the external IP as an acceptable outbound rule. Unfortunately the outbound request still seems to be blocked.

As a further test I have also added 3389 as an acceptable inbound rule to allow RDP to the first of the backend servers. While I can RDP to the fist server in the scaleset, I can still access the other backend services in on RDP ports 3390 and 3391.

Is there something else I need to do to apply the NSG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default NSG doesnt block outbound requests, so you would first need to block all outbound requests and then allow your specific ones.

not sure about the RDP problem, are you using NATting? Never saw VMSS available on 3390 or 3391? In case you are - you need to apply NSG to a load balancers Subnet.

Comment: The initial rules created along with the NSG started with a rule that blocked all outbound traffic. I added a higher priority rule that allowed traffic on port 22 (for SFTP). There is a load balancer in front if the backend VMSS, and the NSG is applied to the same subnet.

Comment: ok, you probably mean inbound? because outbound traffic doesnt get blocked by default. are the load balancer and vmss in the same subnet?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes they are both in the same subnet. When I created the NSG there were three outbound rules created by default, priority 65500 blocking all outbound traffic, then 65001 allowing outbound internet then 65000 allowing outbound VNET.

Comment: I added a priority 100 rule allowing outbound port 22 traffic

Comment: exactly, so they are not blocking outbound connection to internet or to the vnet. which means nothing gets blocked. so thats pretty much impossible

Comment: Looks like you were right, it was the external API blocking inbound requests from the VNET IP. Thanks.